# Curves where holomorphic function is real valued through a critical point.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f:\Omega\to \mathbb{C}$ be a holomorphic function, where $\Omega$ is an open set containing $\alpha\in \mathbb{R}$, and suppose that $f\big|_{\Omega \hspace{0.5mm} \cap \hspace{0.5mm}\mathbb{R}}$ is real valued (so that $f^{(k)}(\alpha)$ are real valued for all $k$). Suppose that $f'(\alpha)=0$ and that $f''(\alpha)\ne 0$.

For $r>0$ such that $\{z\in \mathbb{C}:|z-\alpha|\le r\}\subset \Omega$, define $g=g_{r}:[0,2\pi)\to \mathbb{C}$ by

$$g(\theta)=f(\alpha+r\text{e}^{\theta i}).$$

I am trying to prove that there exists a $r_0>0$, such that for all $0<r\le r_0$, there are exactly four distinct values $\theta_1, \theta_2, \theta_3, \theta_4\in [0,2\pi)$ such that $g(\theta_i)\in \mathbb{R}$.

**What I amble to do, and where my approach falls short.**

If we use a power series expansion about $\alpha$, we have
$$f(\alpha+r\text{e}^{\theta i})=f(\alpha)+\frac{1}{2}r^2\text{e}^{2\theta i}f''(\alpha)+R(r,\theta)$$
with $R(r,\theta)=O(r^3)$ uniformly in $\theta$ as $r\to 0^{+}$. If $C>0$ is such that $|R(r,\theta)|\le Cr^3$ for $r$ sufficiently small, then by geometric considerations, the argument of $\frac{1}{2}r^2\text{e}^{2\theta i}f''(\alpha)+R(r,\theta)$ cannot differ from $2\theta=\text{arg}(\frac{1}{2}r^2\text{e}^{2\theta i}f''(\alpha))$ by more than $\theta^{\ast}$, as shown in the image below:

[image]

Here $P=\frac{1}{2}r^2\text{e}^{2\theta i}f''(\alpha)$, $|P-Q|=Cr^3$ and $\angle P Q 0$ is a right angle. Thus, $\theta^{\ast}=\arcsin(\frac{2Cr}{f''(\alpha)})=O(r)$ as $r\to 0^{+}$. This allows me to write
$$f(\alpha+r\text{e}^{\theta i})-f(\alpha)=(\frac{1}{2}r^2f''(\alpha)+O(r^3))\text{e}^{(2\theta +O(r))i}.$$
For sufficiently small $r$, this allows me to conclude that there are at least four values of $\theta$  such that $g(\theta)$ is real valued, given by
$$\theta_1=0, \hspace{4mm} \theta_2\approx \frac{\pi}{2}, \hspace{4mm} \theta_3=\pi, \hspace{4mm} \theta_3\approx \frac{3\pi}{2}.$$

The problem is that I am unable to show that there are exactly 4 zeros when $r$ is sufficiently small.

I have tried bounding the number of zeros of
$$h(z)=\frac{1}{2i}(f(\alpha+r\text{e}^{zi})-f(\alpha+r\text{e}^{-zi}))$$
on the real line using different techinques, but the bounds I get are not much better than 16 zeros, which is not good enough (you may assume that $f$ satisfies $f(\overline{z})=\overline{f(z)}$).

I also had the idea to consider the stable and unstable manifolds of the dymaical system $x'(t)=f'(x(t))$ near the critical point $x=\alpha$, but this did not lead anywhere.

Besides the values $\theta=0$ and $\theta=\pi$, where $f$ is definitely real valued, I may compute for $\xi=u+iv$ that
$$\text{Im}f(\alpha+\xi)=f''(\alpha)uv+\frac{1}{6}f^{3}(\alpha)(3u^2v-v^3)+\frac{1}{6}f^{(4)}(\alpha)(u^3v-uv^3)+O(|\xi|^5).$$
If I set the left hand size equal to zero and ignore the big $O$-term, then I get an approximation for the nontrivial curve through $\alpha$ for which $f(z)$
is real valued:

$$v=\pm \sqrt{\frac{6f''(\alpha)+3f^{(3)}(\alpha)u^2+f^{(4)}(\alpha)u^3}{f^{(3)}(\alpha)+f^{(4)}(\alpha) u}}$$
(assuming $f^{(3)}(\alpha)$ and $f^{(4)}(\alpha)$ are not both zero).

There may be a very simple way to prove the statement, but I am unable to see it.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: By a translation in the variable and one by$f(\alpha)$ real as well as a scaling by a non zero real, neither changing hypothesis or conclusion, assume $f(0)=f'(0)=0, f"(0) \ne 0$ and $f(z)=z^2+z^3h(z)$ for $|z|$ small enough where $h$ is analytic  near zero and $f'$ is  non zero there too; use Rouche then to show $f(z)-a, z^2-a$ have same number of roots for small $a$ and in particularly choosing values $a=\pm x$ for small $|x|$ real it follows that $f$ has $2$ distinct roots for each such $x\ne 0$ because derivative nonzero; then the preimages are two disjoint analytic rays except at origin

Comment: (Continued) so four analytic Jordan rays, two for each $(-x_0,0], [0,x_0)$ where $x_0$ is small enough, each starting at origin, ending at $f(\pm x_0)$ and non intersecting so intersect every small enough circle in $4$ points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on the comment that reduces $f(z)= z^2 + o(z^2)$ near the origin, argue next that $f(z)= g^2(z)$ where $g(z)= z+ \ldots$ has power series whose coefficients are uniquely determined recursively and are real-valued (analytic Morse Lemma).  Note that $w=g(z)$ is locally 1-1 and onto and must assume values on the four coordinate axes of the $w$ plane. Consider the inverse image by $g$ of these axes. On these four arcs in the $z$ plane, $f(z)$ is real-valued. P.S. Note in fact that the four arcs consist of really just two smooth arcs that cross  orthogonally at the origin.